# ACCOUNT_UNAVAILABLE alert on signing to Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

I created a new Apple ID and tried to use it in the same Macbook Pro 2016 as the old account. I've logged out and tried to log in with new credentials, after that I've seen an alert with terms to accept (I accepted it), then just "ACCOUNT_UNAVAILABLE" alert without any details. What does it mean?

Also, tried to update Macbook to the newest version (currently - 11.6 Big Sur), but without any change.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you use the new Apple ID to log into appleid.apple.com?

Comment: Have you restarted your computer

Comment: Yes, I can. I also have my MacBook listed in the devices section. What do you mean by restarting the computer? I've tried to run again, but without any result.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, how?